# How to go through facebook review process on existing site with high traffic?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I have **already implemented facebook login/signup** on a site, using a combination of the Javascript and PHP SDKs. I remember that the review process took about a day or two. That was for a brand new site.

Now I need to add the same functionality to another site that exists and currently has hundreds of visitors per day. **I have already implemented the changes and it works fine in sandbox mode but here's my question:**

When I upload the new code, and until the facebook app is reviewed and accepted, there will be two buttons "login with facebook" and "signup with facebook" **that will not be operational**. This might confuse some users and have a negative impact on the perceived credibility of the site. **These buttons need to be on the same screen next to the standard email/password forms.**

Is there something I can do about this? **Can I hide the buttons from the general population until the app is reviewed?** Is there some specific GET parameter that the testers send to the server to know that a request is for review purposes? What do other web developers do in this situation?

Comment: I don't get it. How is the review process (do you mean the [Open Graph Submission Process](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process/) or the [App Center review](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appcenter/guidelines/)?) interrelated with the [Facebook login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/) or [registering with Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/)? Could you please reiterate on this a little more?

Comment: @Lego OK thanks for the links, I think I see now why I was confused. Last time I created an app that let you do login/signup and also posted on users' walls. Maybe that's why I had to go through the review process? What you're saying is that for simple login/signup without post permissions or otherwise modifying the graph I won't have to go through any review process? If that's so, please write your answer below so I can accept it. Also, I didn't know about the registration plugin. Thanks.

Comment: Only if you want to use (custom) Open Graph actions in your app, you have to get those approved by Facebook first. For a simple login with Facebook feature there’s no review necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to implement a [Facebook Login for Web](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/) or a user registration by using the [Facebook registration plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/), you won't need to go through any review process.

Comment: just make sure you have the contact email filled out.